# Twiiter4j API Tutorial

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have gone through a lot of blogs and tutorials for using Twitter 4j library 
for writing a simple tweet through program but very less were useful. Can 
somebody provide me with a site with good tutorial regarding the steps for 
the same.

Answer (score 5):

Do u have a specific question, because right on twitter4j.org has a howto with example: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 2):

check this out. see if it brings to you any use.
http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/quick-tutorial-twitter-processing

i realize you may have used that now that you said "blogs". This may help, its in line with Twitter's migration to Java for many site elements. Check it out.
http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/retrieve-tweets-using-twitter4j

Answer (score 2):

If you will download [twitter4j-2.2.5](http://twitter4j.org/en/twitter4j-2.2.5.zip) Jar file. It will have a twitter4j-examples folder.You can get examples of all functions for twitter there.
But before using that , you need to get consumer secret/token and access token/secret from [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find exactly what you need here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/